# CreateConsoleScreenBuffer returning invalid but not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application, handle

I'm creating a new console screen buffer and trying to set it as the active screen buffer of a new console created via CreateProcessA(), but when the new console is created it shows something like "Unable to write on specified device."; also, the main console window gets so small that you can only see it's titlebar.

```
STARTUPINFOA start_info {};

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec_attr {};

sec_attr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sec_attr.nLength = sizeof(sec_attr);
sec_attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

HANDLE handle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    &sec_attr,
    CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
    NULL
);

CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX buffer_info {};

buffer_info.cbSize = sizeof(buffer_info);

buffer_info.dwSize.X = 120;
buffer_info.dwSize.Y = 120;

buffer_info.srWindow.Top = 0;
buffer_info.srWindow.Left = 0;

buffer_info.srWindow.Bottom = 119;
buffer_info.srWindow.Right = 119;

SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(
    handle,
    &buffer_info
);

start_info.cb = sizeof(start_info);
start_info.lpTitle = "prova";
start_info.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
start_info.hStdOutput = handle;

PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;

CreateProcessA(
    NULL,
    "cmd",
    &sec_attr,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &start_info,
    &process_info
);
```

Comment: I fixed it and I'm still getting "invalid handle" in the new console. Also, now the main console is so small that only the title bar is visible. I don't know what's going on

Comment: Does it work with the non-Ex version?

Comment: SetConsoleScreenBufferInfo doesn't seem to exist

Comment: NB. buffer_info.dwSize is in character units while buffer_info.srWindow is in pixels !

Comment: _"If lpSecurityAttributes is NULL, the handle cannot be inherited."_ is a bit of a problem when _"If this flag is specified when calling one of the process creation functions, the handles must be inheritable and the function's bInheritHandles parameter must be set to TRUE."_ e.g. you have a non-inheritable `HANDLE` getting passed to a method that requires inheritance. You also need to set `bInheritHandles` to `TRUE`

Comment: I changed it and now I'm getting something like "unable to write on specified device". Main console is still just a title bar.

Comment: @DarkoNaito_09 I believe that's because the process is [expecting a pipe or file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) and not a console buffer.